# MonoTouchDesignServerUnified quit unexpectedly

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, air

Hello I am creating a iOS application using Xamarin and the most recent version of Visual Studio for Mac.

I keep getting an alert box error whenever I run the simulator that states:

**MonoTouchDesignServerUnified quit unexpectedly.**

The error report says:

*Application Specific Information:
abort() called
CoreSimulator 375.21 - Device: iPad Air - Runtime: iOS 10.3 (14E269) - DeviceType: iPad Air*

How do I get rid of this error?

Comment: I took a Xamarin University course tonight - the instruction was to click "Ignore" until they fix the bug. It's annoying, but harmless.

Answer (score 1):

Open the storyboard file as text and remove the "Device" element from the top of the storyboard. 
Looks like:

```
<device id="retina4_0" orientation="portrait">
    <adaptation id="fullscreen"/>
</device>
```

Save the changes, go to Visual Studio, make a build "Clean all" and then try to open again your storyboard